# Combination problem (solution verification)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Please, verify what is wrong with my solution.

We have 9 black balls and 6 white balls in a box. How many ways we can take 5 balls from the box?

Solution: If b=black and w=white then, we can have 5b balls or 4b 1w or 3b 2w or 2b 3w or 1b 4w or 5w. Therefore, the number of possibilities are $$\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{9}{5-k}\binom{6}{k}=2997$$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you forget the last pattern? (or typo?)

The answer is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{9}{5-k}\binom{6}{k}=3003.$$

**P.S.** Your idea is perfect.

Comment: Yes, I forget it haha. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Your idea is perfect!

Comment: Thank you. I was solving this problem for a friend, but the answer is $3003$, however, as you saw in my post, my answer was wrong, because I forgot the last term of the sum.

Comment: Kind of you. Calculation is of course important, but the idea is also important.